# How to make a functor from a member function?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, functor

I want `run` to call `c.drive()`:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct Car {
    void drive() { }
};

template <typename Function>
void run(Function f) {
    f();
}

int main() {
    Car c;    
    run(bind1st(mem_fun(&Car::drive), &c));    
    return 0;
}
```

This does not compile and the error messages does not help me:

at f():
no match for call to ‘(std::binder1st<std::mem_fun_t<void, Car> >) ()’

at the call to run:
no type named ‘first_argument_type’ in ‘class std::mem_fun_t<void, Car>’
no type named ‘second_argument_type’ in ‘class std::mem_fun_t<void, Car>’

**No boost please.**

**Update:** even though the problem is solved, I would be very happy to see TR1/C++0x solutions!

Comment: Are you willing to allow `bind` (and such) from TR1 and/or C++0x?

Comment: Yes, I am definitely interested, so please post it! However, I need a final solution in pure C++03.

Comment: Do you wish to do only this way or your motive is to call `run` that calls `c.drive()` any way ( i.e., with out using boost )

Comment: I just want `run` to call `c.drive()`, I do not insist on the particular approach given in the above code. However I do insist on using a functor and I would like to understand what is wrong with my code, i.e. why it fails to compile.

Comment: By the time I posted my code, you changed your comment insisting the use of functor :(

Comment: Sorry... :( I can solve the problem with a pointer to member function but that breaks when I pass an ordinary function to `run`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bind1st` makes a unary function out of a binary function and a value. You are trying to make a function that takes no parameters out of a unary function and there isn't anything to support this in standard C++03.

You will have to do something like this.

```
template<class X, void (X::*p)()>
class MyFunctor
{
    X& _x;
public:
    MyFunctor(X& x) : _x( x ) {}
    void operator()() const { (_x.*p)(); }
};

template <typename Function>
void run(Function f) {
    f();
}

int main() {
    Car c;
    run(MyFunctor<Car, &Car::drive>(c));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can driver be inlined if when calling run(MyFunctor<Car, &Car::drive>(c));

Answer (score 10):

The Boost/TR1/C++0x solution is quite straightforward:

```
run(std::bind(&Car::drive, &c));
```

Answer (score 7):

The C++0x solution using lambdas - http://www.ideone.com/jz5B1 :

```
struct Car {
    void drive() { }
};

template <typename Function>
void run(Function f) {
    f();
}

int main() {
    Car c;    
    run( [&c](){ c.drive(); } );    
    return 0;
}
```